# picker created dynamically?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am new to React Native and to TypeScript. I was wondering if it is possible to create a picker completely dynamically. For instance, instead of using (const [selectedQLType, setQLTypePicker] = useState('');) is it possible to dynamically create those state variable so that you can then generate severals pickers using a map function for instance based on an array of parameters ?

```
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
```

...
const [selectedQLType, setQLTypePicker] = useState('');

```
  return (
    <View>    
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedQLType}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setQLTypePicker(itemValue)}>
        {variableType.map(itemIdx => 
          <Picker.Item 
            label={itemIdx} 
            key={itemIdx} 
            value={itemIdx} 
          />)} 
      </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone end up searching for the same question, the answer is by creating a component and using a method to update the related state variable. 'setQLTypePicker' then is present only inside the component.